# Excel VBA alternative for VLOOKUP when searching the cell value with special characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

What is `VLOOKUP` alternative when searching the cell value with special characters? Or any macro I could use for alternative.
The formula is in Column E and the look up value is Column D. Apparently the `VLOOKUP` is only searching the numbers and text. If the value has special characters it does not display the correct info I need in Column E.

Comment: Can you show how your data looks?

Comment: In the future there would be value in either providing the formula/code you have tried so we can more easily identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have tested that now, and it seems that every special character works for me.
You should always include `0` (or `FALSE`) as the fourth argument in the `VLOOKUP` formula if you need to find the exact match. My guess is that you forgot the zero this time. Even though not VBA, but an alternative for `VLOOKUP` is `=INDEX(MATCH(...,...,0))`. You can google it.